# Unable to get video via uvc_gadget to the host pc

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, uvc

I am trying to setup a raspberry pi board as a piping device which could receive video from a camera or any other source and pipe it to the host pc. I am following the tutorial mentioned here

https://gist.github.com/justinschuldt/36469e2a89d95ef158a8c4df091e9cb4

I am able to successfully stream webcam video to the host pc. What I wanted to do was to use a video file instead of the stream from the webcam. In order to do that I did as follows

- Created a dummy v4l2loopback device
- Created uvc_gadget following the tutorial above

My setup looks like this

[image]

Afterwards I was able to start uvc_gadget as follows
[image]

Now when I tried to stream a video file to /dev/video2 I only got colored stripes on the host pc with the error no jpeg data found

[image]

On host PC

[image]

Error

[image]

I get almost similar behavior if I create a gadget using g_webcam instead of configFS.

Would be thankful for any help. I am assuming there are some issues with the encoding.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)